# Which one is the application server in the given scenario

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a web application in Java 8. It is developed using Spring 4, Hibernate 4 and Maven 3 frameworks. I am deploying the application in Tomcat 8.

Now I have a stupid doubt.

My Web server is Tomcat 8.
But what will be the Application Server..??????

Comment: Tomcat is an application server. You might be confused with the phrases.

Comment: Then which one is the web server.? While searching over net, seems both are different.

Comment: The webserver is the reference to the system which is the roothost, so to say, for your application. You have to run your application server on a webserver to make it public in the web. So commonly you would talk about a piece of hardware, with an server-OS like a windows server. But in the end the phrase isnt rly that concret: it is just a server side system in the web that offers functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is primarily an *application* server, not a *web* server. From the home page, "Apache Tomcat is an open source software implementation of the Java Servlet and JavaServer Pages technologies".

None of those frameworks you've mentioned are the web server either.

As to which web server you're using, that remains unclear. It comes with the Coyote connector component which can provide the web server side of the equation as per the [Tomcat wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat), but it's possible it may be running under a different one.

Comment: Ok. I finalized as application server is Tomcat and web server is Apache